# Laravel Postgres calculate time difference and get min/max

Tags: postgresql, laravel-5

Hi my table structure is like this i am using laravel and postgres database

```
id | serving_start_time      | serving_end_time    
1  | 2016-10-05 00:24:08.894 | 2016-10-05 00:24:19.003    
2  | 2016-10-05 00:24:59.875 | 2016-10-05 00:25:13.728    
3  | 2016-10-05 11:43:52.055 | 2016-10-05 11:45:41.561
```

I want to calculate the 'total_serving_time'(serving_start_time-serving_end_time) and get only the min and max 'total_serving_time'. Is this possible in one query? please help

Comment: Is "total serving time" the sum of all differences? Can you perhaps expand the question to show how you would want the answer to look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In one query like following?

```
SELECT 
    MIN(serving_end_time - serving_start_time) AS min_total_serving_time,
    MAX(serving_end_time - serving_start_time) AS max_total_serving_time
FROM table;
```

Comment: exactly thanks. one more question can we calculate average total_serving_time from same query

Comment: i did it thanks  AVG(serving_end_time - serving_start_time) AS avg_total_serving_time